# C++ error when multiplying #define and const variable

Tags: c++, constants

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

#define LENGTH 10;
#define NEWLINE '\n'
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int area;
    const int WIDTH=20;
    area=LENGTH*WIDTH;   
    cout<<area<<NEWLINE;
    system("pause");
}
```

Error is at line where area is calculated, it says "

> operand of * must be a pointer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not terminate the macro definitions with `;`. Otherwise the expression expands to:

```
area=10;*WIDTH;
```

Now the error makes sense, right?

Answer (score 3):

```
#define LENGTH 10;
```

should be

```
#define LENGTH 10
//               ^ no trailing ;
```

At present, the preprocessor expands your code to

```
area=10;*WIDTH;
//     ^ error
```

Answer (score 2):

Never, ever, terminate a macro with a semicolon.

```
#define LENGTH 10
```

is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are simple text replacements.

Your macro `LENGTH` expands to the tokens `10;`.

Then your statement in `main` is actually two statements:

```
area = LENGTH; *WIDTH
```

This attempts to dereference `WIDTH`, which is not a pointer and therefore cannot be dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition includes a semicolon which would normally end the statement.

```
#define LENGTH 10;
```

Remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Exists error in your LENGTH macros, remove semicolon.

Good: `#define LENGTH 10`

Use the `std::endl` for carriage return.

```
std::cout<< area << std::endl;
```

Comment: No, `'\n` is a perfectly valid _newline_. You only use `std::endl` if you require stream flushing, too. To be fair, right before a `system("pause")`, you probably do require stream flushing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The default is more or less the opposite.  You only replace `std::endl` with `'\n'` when you explicitly know that you don't want to flush.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Why's that? Flushing is an expense you usually don't need. Let the buffers do their job.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If it turns out to be too expensive, then you can come back and turn it off, but doing so earlier is clearly premature optimization.  And can make it more difficult to debug the code.

Comment: I don't think it is a premature optimization. I think it is "write your program accurately according to requirements". And certainly writing your program to be "not as inefficient as possible" is not the same as "prematurely optimizing", especially with I/O. If you require immediate flushing, go ahead and write that. If you require `\n` to be output then write `\n`. It's all subjective, I suppose, and your argument that it can produce surprising results that slow debugging is certainly a valid one. I'm just a little surprised as I've never heard this viewpoint before. :)